# How to convert this into a telescopic sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, telescopic-series

I'm trying to convert this series into a telescopic series but I'm stuck on making it
into a telescopic form by factoring it, tried partial faction decomposing it but couldn't proceed any further because of imaginary number.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3-1}$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3070418/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853557/42969.